# setting up exim4 for vep

Tags: exim

I have exim4 running on a Debian server. A couple of applications send VERP mail from specific domains.

Reading the [exim docs](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-some_common_configuration_settings.html) it suggests a **router** that looks for certain domains and passes off to a special **transport** for which is sensitive to VERP (i.e. it does not mangle individual return paths by using `max_rcpt = 1`)

The exim docs example use a hard-coded regex to identify the domain (and, in the example the local part suffix `-request` but I don't need that).

I would like to write a router that identifies whether the return_path that is set is one from a list of given domains, and if so, use the special verp transport.

I'd like to maintain the list of domains in a list rather than keep editing a regexp as I believe this will make for a more robust config file!

Normally in Exim I could do something like `domains = +some_domain_list` but this only works to test the destination domain; I want to test the `return_path` domain.

i.e. I want to do something like:

```
# domains that are used for VERP
my_domains_list = foo.example.com : bar.org

# my router
myrouter:
   driver = dnslookup
   return_path_domains = +my_domains_list
   transport = verp_sensitive_transport
```